# Heatmap of categorical variable counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, categorical-data, pheatmap

I have a data frame of items, and each has multiple classifier columns that are categorical variables.

```
ID    test1    test2     test3
1     A        B         A
2     B        A         C
3     C        C         C
4     A        A         B
5     B        B         B
6     B        A         C
```

I want to generate a heatmap for each combination of test columns (test1 v test2, test1 v test3, etc.) using ggplot2. 
The heatmap would have all factors in that test's column (in this case A,B,C) on the x-side and all factors of the other test on the y-side, and the boxes in the heatmap should be colored based on the count of ids that have that combination of classifier.

For example in the above input, if we have heatmap between test1 and test2, then the box that is in the intersection of B for test1 and A for test2 would be brightest, since there are 2 ids with that combination.
I hope to use these heatmaps to analyze which tests are most congruent for the data set, but can't use a Pearson's R correlation since they are categorical variables.

I am familiar with ggplot, which is why I prefer that package, but if it is easier in pheatplot, I am okay with learning that.

Comment: It seems like your description of the heatmap would have A,B,C on the x-axis and A,B,C on the y-axis ... but your tests have three columns, not two. It might help if you include a plot from `pheatmap` and the code used to generate it (from this sample data).

Comment: Sorry I guess I wasn't clear. I want a figure for each combination of columns, where the factors of those two columns are on the axes. So for this sample data, I'd want 3 different graphs. If I could generate the plot using pheatmap, I wouldn't need to ask the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took some time to realize how to do it, and still I am not sure it is the best way.

Data:

```
dat = structure(list(ID = 1:6, 
                     test1 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B"), 
                     test2 = c("B", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A"), 
                     test3 = c("A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "C")
                     ), 
                .Names = c("ID", "test1", "test2", "test3"), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L)
                )
```

Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(gridExtra)
```

Create all all combinations of factors (also tests) taken 2 at a time

```
fcombs <- expand.grid(LETTERS[1:3], LETTERS[1:3], stringsAsFactors = F)
tcombs <- as.data.frame(combn(colnames(dat[,-1]), 2), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

`lapply` through the tests combinations, `full_join`, count length of each group excluding `NA`s

```
dtl <- lapply(tcombs, function(i){
        select(dat, ID, i) %>%
        full_join(x = fcombs, by = c("Var1" = i[1], Var2 = i[2])) %>%
        group_by(Var1, Var2) %>%
        mutate(N = sum(!is.na(ID)), ID = NULL) %>%
        ungroup()
  }
)
```

Create a list of plots

```
pl <- lapply(seq_along(tcombs), function(i){
        gtitle = paste(tcombs[[i]], collapse = " ~ ")
        dtl[[i]] %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = N)) +
        geom_tile() +
        theme_tufte() +
        theme(axis.title = element_blank()) +
        ggtitle(gtitle)
        }
      )
```

Create list of tables (`tableGrob` objects)

```
tbl <- lapply(tcombs, function(i) tableGrob(select(dat, ID, i),  
                                            theme = ttheme_minimal()))
```

Put everything into the resulting list and plot

```
resl <- c(pl, tbl)[c(1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6)]

grid.arrange(grobs = resl, ncol = 2, nrow = 3)
```

[image: heatmaps]

Answer (score 2):

Your question is bit unclear, but I think you are looking for something like this. I am not a ggplot2 person so I will let someone else provide that code.

```
x <- read.table(text="ID    test1    test2     test3
                1     A        B         A
                2     B        A         C
                3     C        C         C
                4     A        A         B
                5     B        B         B
                6     B        A         C", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=T)

xl <- reshape2::melt(data = x, id.vars="ID", variable.name = "Test", value.name="Grade")
xl$Test_Gr <- apply(xl[,2:3], 1, paste0, collapse="_")

xw <- reshape2::dcast(xl, ID ~ Test_Gr, fun.aggregate = length)
xwm <- as.matrix(xw[,-1])
xc <- t(xwm) %*% xwm
colnames(xc) <- colnames(xw)[-1]
rownames(wc) <- colnames(xw)[-1]
gplots::heatmap.2(xc, trace="none", col = rev(heat.colors(15)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is kind of what I was looking for. I really wanted 3 seperate heatmaps, one for Test1 vs Test2, Test1 vs Test3, and Test2 vs Test3. But I will work with this code you provided and figure out how it works. Thanks!

Comment: I just went through your code and saw how it works. I think I can fairly easily adapt it to create the heatmaps I was originally looking for. Thank you for showing me the dcast and melt methods!